# if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) this condition is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Actually I am working on a chatbox....But It doesn't meet this condition.
   Here is the code

```
function submitChat() {
  if (form1.users.value == "" || form1.messege.value == "") {
    alert("Please fill the all feild");
    return;
  }
  var users = form1.users.value;
  var messege = form1.messege.value;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Here is the problem may be
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementByID('shouts').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'process.php?users' + users + '&messege' + messege, 'true');
  xmlhttp.send();
```

Here these variable shows undefined..

```
$users = $_REQUEST['users'];
$messege =  $_REQUEST['messege'];
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: @nikunjMnage He's not using jQuery.

Comment: Your query string is malformed, names and values need to be separated by a `=` character

Comment: `console.log(xmlhttp);` before your if, see what those properties are set to

Answer (score 1):

You've left out the `=` between the parameter names and their values.

Also, when you're sending a URL parameter that could include special characters, you need to encode it properly, using `encodeURIComponent()`

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'process.php?users=' + encodeURIComponent(users) + '&messege=' + encodeURIComponent(messege), true);
```

Note also that the third argument should be a boolean, not a string (although since any non-empty string is truthy, `'true'` will have the same effect as `true`, but `'false'` would not be equivalent to `false`).

It's also not usually a good idea to use a URL parameter for long inputs like messages, you should use `POST` data instead.

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
xmlhttp.send('users=' + encodeURIComponent(users) + '&messege=' + encodeURIComponent(messege));
```

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                         document.getElementByID('shouts').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

Comment: Still now It doesn;t meet this condition ...Is there any problem here?

Comment: Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see if there's an error from the AJAX request.

Comment: 2(index):28 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function
                 at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ((index):28)

Comment: `ByID` should be `ById`.

Comment: include 'database.php';
$users = $_REQUEST['users'];
$messege =  $_REQUEST['messege'];
     
$query1= mysqli_query("INSERT INTO souts('users','messege') VALUES('$users','$messege')");


$result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM souts");

   while ($extract= mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
          
            echo $extract['users'] . " :" . $extract['messege'] . "</br>";

        }

Comment: Don't try to put long code in comments. Edit the question

Comment: Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what parameters you're sending.

Comment: The code is not interesting. `$_REQUEST` is set automatically.

Comment: Doesn't shows anything error or parameters in Network tab..Bro

Comment: When you set a breakpoint before `xmlhttp.send`, do you see the correct values in `users` and `messege`?

Comment: Yeah I get the value of user and messege brfore xmlhttp.send

Comment: Check the `request_order` setting in `php.ini` to make sure it's filling in this variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

Comment: What does `var_dump($_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET);` show?

Comment: Shows array(0) { }

Comment: I am sure that this code is not working     $users = $_REQUEST['users'];

Comment: Are you using `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: I am Using  POST

Comment: Do other PHP scripts on your server get their parameters properly?

Comment: Yeah ..working only users and messege is in the problem